# Beamer left margin setting does not remove whitespace

Tags: beamer, margins, block, white-space

Using beamer, I am widening block size by 1.05X to get more text inside, using the command

```
\usepackage{changepage}
\addtobeamertemplate{block begin}{%
        \setlength{\textwidth}{1.05\textwidth}
    }{}
```

Next, now that the block is wider, I want to reduce the left margin so that the block's left edge moves more to the left, and the whitespace becomes more narrow. However, it seems that the margin command cannot move the left side of the block beyond some threshold.

In other words, the command:

```
\setbeamersize{text margin left=-10mm, text margin right=0mm}
```

does not result in a smaller left margin than leaving the distance at zero:

```
\setbeamersize{text margin left=0mm, text margin right=0mm}
```

So what command can reduce the whitespace on the left side, so that the block moves more leftward?

In the pic below, you can see the block is widened slightly by a factor of 1.05, and hence, I need to move the block more leftward to center it.

[image]

Comment: Please do not add a solution to your question!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would suggest to use `columns` to temporarily change the margins:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usetheme{Warsaw}

\addtobeamertemplate{block begin}{%
  \begin{columns}
  \begin{column}{1.05\textwidth}
}{}

\addtobeamertemplate{block end}{}{
  \end{column}
  \end{columns}
  \vskip0.3cm
}


\begin{document}
    
\begin{frame}
    Nam dui ligula, fringilla a, euismod sodales, sollicitudin vel, wisi. Morbi auctor lorem non justo. Nam lacus libero, pretium at,
  
  \begin{block}{title}
  Nam dui ligula, fringilla a, euismod sodales, sollicitudin vel, wisi. Morbi auctor lorem non justo. Nam lacus libero, pretium at,
  \end{block}
  
  Nam dui ligula, fringilla a, euismod sodales, sollicitudin vel, wisi. Morbi auctor lorem non justo. Nam lacus libero, pretium at,
\end{frame} 
    
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

or you could use the `tcolorbox` inner theme which replaces the normal blocks with tcolorboxes:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usetheme{Warsaw}

\useinnertheme{tcolorbox}

\tcbsetforeverylayer{
  grow to left by=6mm,
  grow to right by=4mm
}

\begin{document}
    
\begin{frame}
    Nam dui ligula, fringilla a, euismod sodales, sollicitudin vel, wisi. Morbi auctor lorem non justo. Nam lacus libero, pretium at,
  
  \begin{block}{title}
  Nam dui ligula, fringilla a, euismod sodales, sollicitudin vel, wisi. Morbi auctor lorem non justo. Nam lacus libero, pretium at,
  \end{block}
  
  Nam dui ligula, fringilla a, euismod sodales, sollicitudin vel, wisi. Morbi auctor lorem non justo. Nam lacus libero, pretium at,
\end{frame} 
    
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, it works perfectly, and centers the wider (1.05X) blocks.  (didn't use tcolorbox, used columns approach).

Comment: @user0123456789 You're welcome!

Comment: In the first line of the slide, I just noticed the gap (whitespace) after ``$Y$,``, which looks annoying. I don't think LaTeX2e (TexWorks) would do that(?), so is that a beamer issue?  Should I simply move the comma inside the in-line equation like ``$Y,$``?

Comment: @user0123456789 Nothing to do with beamer, you get the same space in normal latex, too.

Comment: Yeah, I guess because it's an italicized upper case character the comma is rendered after the top right of the character.

Comment: I posted a Resolved paragraph entry in the OP, with a pic of the fixed problem, but the moderator is adamant about closing the question. Already flagged, and said closure doesn't make sense.  Question is clear, code used that didn't resolve was provided, plus an image.

Comment: @user0123456789 You really shouldn't edit your post to include such things like a resolved paragraph. I rolled back this edit.

Comment: @user0123456789 About the closure: I already voted to reopen and the question is currently under review in the reopen queue. Let's see if others agree.

Comment: @user0123456789 "code used that didn't resolve was provided" -> it would be better if you would have posted a compilable minimal working example instead of just a couple of fragments one needs to puzzle together before one can even start to work on your problem.

Comment: Preamble's too large with superfluous information to make the resulting slides (pic shown in OP), as there's a lot of code to make larger balls, change ball color, colored framebox for equations, etc. But I could try minimal example, but not today.