# Define a script environment in Beamer

Tags: beamer, environments

I would like to have a script environment where I could write scripts for every slide.

I don't know if Beamer has such an environment, so I try to create my own as follows.

One problem of this setting is that: since `block1` and `block2` are separated by new lines, I would like `block2` to have an indentation before it.

Another problem is we cannot skip a line by `\\\\`  anymore like illustrated by `block3` and `block4`.

I would like the script environment to behave exactly like writing paragraphs and texts in a basic latex document. Could anyone help?

```
\documentclass[11pt]{beamer}

\newenvironment{script} { \scriptsize }

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Problem}
    abc
\end{frame}

\begin{script}
    block1

    block2
\end{script}

\begin{script}
    block3
    \\\\
    block4
\end{script}
\end{document}
```

Comment: `\\\\ ` is wrong and will cause an error. You should not abuse `\\ ` for line breaks.

Comment: I would like to create line breaks as what we can do in a normal latex article environment.

Comment: You shouldn't use `\\\\ ` in article class either. If you want to start a new paragraph, leave an empty line in your source code. If you want some space between the paragraphs, insert something like `\bigskip` in between

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't use `\\` for line breaks, even less so two of these in a row.

Leave an empty line to start a new paragraph and if you'd like some space between the paragraphs, you can add `\smallskip`, `\medskip`, `\bigskip` and similar commands:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{beamer}

\makeatletter
\newenvironment{script}{\setlength{\parindent}{1cm}\@afterindentfalse\@afterheading\scriptsize}{\par}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Problem}
    abc

\begin{script}
    block1

    block2
\end{script}

\begin{script}
    block3\bigskip\linebreak
    block4
\end{script}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I would like `block2` to have an indentation before it.

Comment: @SoftTimur See my edit

Comment: Thank you. Another question: do you know how to make the width of the `script` environment larger than normal beamer slides?

Comment: @SoftTimur You can use columns, as shown here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/660728/36296